# Sequelize 6, delete cascade with M:N association

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, database-design, sequelize.js

I'm trying to define some specific M:N association using sequelize v6.20.1 and i'm facing and issue...

I have 2 models, an `Account` model and a `Group` model.
My rules about these models are the following:

- An account can exists without any group
- An account can have multiple groups
- A group can exists with a least one account associated, so that mean a group cannot exists without an account associated
- A group can be associated with multiple accounts

Here is the code definition of all models and association :

```js
const Sequelize, { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: `./database.sqlite`,
});

/* ----- Account model ----- */

class Account extends Model {
  // Some account's methods definitions...
}
Account.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  username: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: DataTypes.STRING,
  password: DataTypes.STRING,
}, { sequelize });

/* ----- Group model ----- */

class Group extends Model {
  // Some group's methods definitions...
}
Group.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
}, { sequelize });

/* ----- AccountGroup model ----- */

class AccountGroup extends Model {
}
AccountGroup.init({
  AccountId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Account,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
  },
  GroupId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Group,
      key: 'id',
    },
    allowNull: false,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  },
}, {
  sequelize,
  timestamps: false,
});

/* ----- Association definition ----- */

Account.belongsToMany(Group, { through: AccountGroup });
Group.belongsToMany(Account, { through: AccountGroup });

sequelize.authenticate();
sequelize.sync({ force: true };

(async () => {
  const group = new Group({ name: 'Group' });
  await group.save();

  const account = new Account({ name: 'Doe', username: 'John', email: 'john.doe@example.com', password: 'secret' });
  account.addGroup(group);
  await account.save();

  // some processing code...

  await account.destroy();
})();
```

After `account.destroy()` finished, the AccountGroup row is successfully deleted but not the Group. And i want to delete unreferenced groups.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way that the cascading deletes works. In your example, when the Account is deleted, rows in the AccountGroup table may now have an invalid value in their AccountId foreign key column. You are telling the database that when this situation occurs, delete the AccountGroup entirely. Similarly, if you delete a Group, this will cascade down and delete any AccountGroup with that Group as its GroupId.

No such issue arises for the Account or Group tables when an AccountGroup is deleted. They do not contain any foreign keys that have been made invalid.

To find the functionality that you are searching for, deleting any groups that no longer belong to an AccountGroup, you will likely want to put a separate query in your code, or you may be able to use a [Hook](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/) to be executed after an Account is deleted.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your guidance :) So i need to add a afterDestroy hook in Account model that check for orphan Group and delete them, isn't it ?

Maybe this will work : 
```javascript
Account.addHook('afterDestroy', 'deleteInvalidGroups', async (inst) => {
await sequelize.query(`DELETE FROM Groups as g WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM AcountGroup as ag WHERE ag.GroupId = g.id AND ag.AccountId = ${inst.id})`, {
  model: Group,
  mapToModel: true,
});
```

And i'll need t oadd this to afterUpdate too

Comment: So... I added hooks but when i'm trying to destroy an Account instance i get "SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" and no hooks are called...

Comment: I just noticed that you have onDelete: 'RESTRICT' for the AccountId column. That should probably be 'CASCADE'. Restrict tells the database to not allow the account to be deleted if it will cause a foreign key constraint in AccountGroup. As for the hook you've written, on first look that looks fine, though I don't think the options object with model: Group and mapToModel: true do anything.

Comment: Oh yes, i changed that to CASCADE, but default is cascade so i delete them both x)
And now i don't have any error, but hooks are not triggering when i update/delete an Account, should i use afterBulkUpdate & afterBulkDestroy ? What is the diference between bulk and not bulk exactly ?

Comment: bulkUpdate and bulkDestroy are other methods available on the queryInterface class. They're used to update/delete multiple rows at the same time. Probably not what you're looking for. To be totally honest, I've never gotten a hook to execute successfully, though it's been a long time since I've tried. It may be worth posting a separate question for troubleshooting hooks to try to get some new eyes on it.

Comment: ok, i'll try searching by myself before and if i found nothing works i'll create a new thread here :) Thanks for you help !